# Not sure weather to use case or IF statement in this

Tags: sql, if-statement, replace, case

I have two tables. First one being

> Tree2009

and second one being

> Tree2012

. I do not have a single matching unique identifier in both tables. Instead, the unique identifier I use is a combination of two columns, y_coord and x_coord. However, both tables have the same columns. The tree2012 table is just an updated version of table2009, but table2012 has many missing values.

My task is to replace any null values in tree2012.inspect_dt (column name is inspect_dt) with values from tree2009.inspect_dt.

```
if inspect_dt is null
    update tree2012
    set inspect_dt = (SELECT inspect_dt from tree2009 where tree2009.x_coord = tree2012.x_coord and tree2009.y_coord = tree2012.y_coord)
```

so far I have that. I believe I need a if/else statement, or a case. I am not sure how to complete it. I used something like that to replace a less complicated column. but that is how I use both sets of coordinates to use as my unique identifier.

any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Can you please specify the language you're working in?

Comment: I am sorry, it is MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Does "with values from" mean multiple rows from tree2012 could get different values from multiple rows of tree2009?

Comment: Yes, so when a row in tree2012 has the same x_coord and y_coord as a row in tree2009, but has a null value in its inspect_dt column (vs tree2009 having a complete value),

then, tree2009's inspect_dt value should replace tree2012's inspect_dt value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do it in one statement without having to get inspect_dt beforehand:

```
UPDATE tree2012
SET inspect_dt = 
    (   SELECT inspect_dt  
        FROM tree2009 
        WHERE tree2009.x_coord = tree2012.x_coord 
        AND tree2009.y_coord = tree2012.y_coord
            AND tree2009.inspect_dt IS NOT NULL
    )
WHERE inspect_dt IS NULL;
```

You can check it in this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b613/1) to see it running.

If you wanted to do something with the records where inspect_dt is not null, then you could use a case, otherwise, i don't see the point.